# "Running Kubernetes Locally via Docker" Guide is not working at all for MacOS, ssh command just hanging

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am following this Guide at http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/ to start using Kubernetes on MacOS. Is this guide valid?

When I am doing this step:

```
docker-machine sshdocker-machine active-N -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

They command is hanging, no repsponse at all;

Looking at docker ps -l, I have

> CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES  b1e95e26f46d
>   gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v1.2.3 "/hyperkube apiserver"
>   About an hour ago Up About an hour 
>   k8s_apiserver.c08c1df_k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default_d95a6048198f747c5fcb74ee23f1f25c_d0c6d2fc

So it means kubernete is running

I run this command:

```
docker-machine `sshdocker-machine active` -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

I can login to docker machine, then exit, run kubectl get nodes again, hanging, no response

Anything wrong here?
If this step can not pass, how can I use Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

"docker-machine ssh `docker-machine active` -N -L 8080:localhost:8080" sets up a ssh tunnel. Similar to ssh tunnel, you can run that command in the background by passing the `-f` option. More useful tips [here](https://gist.github.com/scy/6781836)

I'd recommend running the ssh command in a separate terminal, so that it will be easy to bring down the tunnel.
As long as the above command is running, `kubectl` should work.